# Merging multiple series in loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, merge, series

So I have a list of series as the following:

```
groupdf1
Out[304]: 
[90-95    9
 >100     1
 80-90    1
 50-80    1
 Name: bucket, dtype: int64, 80-90     9
 95-100    1
 90-95     1
 50-80     1
 Name: bucket, dtype: int64, 80-90    10
 90-95     1
 50-80     1
 Name: bucket, dtype: int64, 80-90     11
 95-100     1
 Name: bucket, dtype: int64, 50-80    9
```

What I'm trying is to create a dataframe like the following:

```
      bucket.1  bucket.2 bucket.3 bucket.4
90-95   9         1         1        NaN
>100    1        NaN       NaN       NaN
80-90   1         9        10        11
50-80   1         1         1        NaN
95-100 NaN       NaN       NaN        1
```

which is basically merging each of the series on the index. I'm not being able to run it in a loop. I'm getting the following error:

```
groupdf=pd.DataFrame(groupdf1[0])
for i in range(1,len(groupdf1)):
    groupdf2=pd.DataFrame(groupdf1[i])
    groupdf.concat(groupdf2)


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-278-4c8876ecdb74>", line 4, in <module>
    groupdf.concat(groupdf2)

  File "C:\Users\hp1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'
```

Can somebody please help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `groupdf1` is list of `DataFrame`s use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and then set new columns names by `enumerate` with `f-string`s:

```
df = pd.concat(groupdf1, axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{x}.{i}' for i, x in enumerate(df.columns, 1)]
#alternative
#df.columns = [f'bucket.{i}' for i in np.arange(1,len(df.columns) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s pandas.concat ... a DataFrame object doesn’t have that attribute. Try pandas.concat((df1, df2)), or whatever your dataframes are named. As jezrael pointed out, pd.concat takes any interval of dataframes, so just pass the axis=1 parameter to concatenate, column-wise.